# Hide url extension

Tags: asp.net

I want to hide or modify the url extension by default it is set to aspx. Can it be modified in asp.net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use URL rewriting.

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Probably you're trying to create friendly urls. If this is the case you need to use "URL rewriting". We could give you more info if you tell us which version of the .NET framework you're using and the version of the IIS.

[Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewrite_engine) you'll find a general definition of url rewriting.  Once you provide extra information about your infraestructure we can point you to the correct tool.